# How to fetch databases by name?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, fetch

I have 4 databases:

```
auth ; auth_backup ; auth1 ; auth1_backup ;
```

I want to fetch only the ones with the "_backup" extension.Is there a way?

**Just with php and sql.And if its possible with mysql not mysqli(i know its deprecate but i have to use it**

Until now i  tried:

```
      $sql4="SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%backup%'"; 
      $query4=mysql_query($sql4,$connect);  
      $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)
```

but in this way,it doesnt work what i am trying to do.So i need something somehow to fetch only the specific dbs.Also if its possible to drop some specific dbs,this will do it too..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following statement:

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` LIKE '%_backup'
```

This will fetch the databases for you with the name _backup in it.

Comment: as i've said above,i already tried this.yes it works,but in my case  is not good.I need a different way to do it.

Comment: @Memphistoles what's so `not good` about it, plz be a bit more specific, since you say it does work, but not the way you like, what's your issue? Besides that, in the above you tried `'%backup%'` *not* `'%_backup'` ;)

Comment: what i gave above was just an example,not my real code.My issues is not about my code,it is just curiosity if there is another way to do this thing